# How to query MongoDB inside for loop without skipping results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

My database has three collections, challenges, users and entries. Challenges have fields like title, description and challenge id. Entries are the completed challenges and contain fields like user id, challenge id and image. I want to join the data in entry collection to it's corresponding challenge so I could have a document containing challenge title, description, challenge id and image. 
I am trying to query the challenges collection based on an array of id's gotten from entries collection and then adding the entry query result as a new field to the document.
 I have implemented a for loop, which allows me to query with a different id each time. I would like to add the result of the query to an array, but sometimes it skips the results and only some of the queries are present in the resulting array. For example, when I send the API call for the first time, the server returns 2 JSON-objects in an array, but the next time it only returns one. I think there is something wrong with the synchronization of the for loop and the queries. How can I make it return the correct documents every time? Also, is there a better way to join the two collections together without a for loop?

I've tried countless of different ways to finish the for loop without skipping any queries or returning the finished array too early,but have failed to do so. This current implementation works on the first API call, but on the next one it fails. I am using MongoDB (and MERN stack) and I have a REST API where I send calls from my React front end.

```
 exports.getDoneChallenges = [check("userId").isLength({ min: 24 }),
  function(req, res) {
    var myPromise = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Find all challenges the user has completed.
      Entry.find({ userId: req.params.id }, { _id: 0 })
      .sort({ challengeId: -1 })
      .exec()
      .then(result => {
        // Check if the user hasn't completed any challenges.
        if (!result) {
          console.log("Zero completed challenges.");
          res
            .status(401)
            .json({ message: "No completed challenges found." });
        } else {
          // Save the completed challenge's identifiers in an array.
          var ids = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            // Cast identifiers to ObjectID
            ids.push(ObjectID(result[i].challengeId));
          }
          // Array of completed challenges + images relating to each.
          var challenge_arr = new Array();

          for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            // Match the corresponding challenge id's from entries to 
             challenges and add image as a new field.
            Challenge.aggregate([
              { $match: { challengeId: ids[i] } },
              { $addFields: { image: result[i] } }
            ])
              .exec()
              .then(challenge => {
                /* Create a new object, which has the needed fields for 
                the response.*/
                var challenge_obj = new Object();
                challenge_obj.title = challenge[0].title;
                challenge_obj.challengeId = challenge[0].challengeId;
                challenge_obj.description = challenge[0].description;
                challenge_obj.date = challenge[0].image.date;
                challenge_obj.img = challenge[0].image.img;

                // Save the challenges into the challenge array.
                challenge_arr.push(challenge_obj);
                console.log(i)
                /* If the loop is in the last round, return the filled 
                array.*/
                if (i == result.length - 1) {
                  // Return the filled array.
                  return challenge_arr;
                }
              })
              .then(challenge_arr => {
                // Check that the array isn't undefined.
                if (typeof challenge_arr !== "undefined") {
                  // Resolve the promise.
                  resolve(challenge_arr);
                }
              });
          }
        }
      });
  });
  // Call promise function and send a response after resolving it.
    myPromise().then(data => {
      res.status(200).json({ data: data });
    });
  }
  ];


var EntrySchema = new Schema({
  challengeId: ObjectId,
  userId: ObjectId,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String}
})


var ChallengeSchema = new Schema({
  challengeId: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  title: String,
  description: String,
  date: {type: Date}
})
```

I have two entries in the Entries collection, which have the same challenge id's as two of the challenges in challenge collection. I query the challenge collection with the id's of the entries, and I am supposed to get 2 documents which have the corresponding entry field added. Sometimes I get the documents correctly, but most of the time it only returns some of them. For example, from 4 expected documents, it returns {chall 1, null, chall 2, chall 3}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can help you orchestrate multiple promises rather than using a `for` loop. The way you currently have it, you end up calling `resolve` when the last loop is done with its work, and not when *every* loop is done with its work.

It might look something like:

```
const promises = result.map((image, i) => 
            Challenge.aggregate([
              { $match: { challengeId: ids[i] } },
              { $addFields: { image } }
            ]).exec());
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((promise_results) => ...);
```

Using `async/await` can generally make code like this much simpler to write and understand:

```
for (const result of results) {
  const challenge = await Challenge.aggregate(...
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! The response time also came down from 1200ms to 20ms, so it's even better in that way. Thank you!